# Can I use developer tools in Chrome to hide all the images on a webpage?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-devtools

Is it possible to hide all the images on a webpage by putting a global class something like this:

```
img{
   display:none; 
}
```

on the entire html document I visit in my browser? Is there a way I can visit a webpage, open up developer tools and override the css classes (locally of course) without having to say `display: none` for every element with the `element.style` class?

Comment: There are tons of web developer extensions to do that

Comment: You can actually do that from the Chrome Settings.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Thanks guys. I think the settings would be the easiest choice

Answer (score 5):

In Chrome Dev Tools (F12), click the plus in the top right, then use your selector. Keep in mind that when you refresh the page, this rule will disappear.

[image]

Otherwise you can disable images in Chrome's settings, click Show advanced settings, then under Privacy, click Content settings

[image]

Comment: oh yes, someone in the comments told me I can go through the settings. I found that. i tried what you did in the first solution there before I asked the question and it didn't work for me.

Comment: That's fine, just was showing you in case you still needed it.